# Cannot withdraw token with openzeppelin postdelivery

Tags: solidity, contract-design, tokens

I'm deploying either token and crowdsale without problems, the crowdsale contract its based on the openzeppelin PostDeliveryCrowdsale.

Crowdsale:

```
contract PorrolhoTokenCrowdsale is PostDeliveryCrowdsale {

    constructor(uint256 _openingTime, uint256 _closingTime, uint256 _rate, address _wallet, uint256 _goal, ERC20 _token) public
    Crowdsale(_rate, _wallet, _token)
    TimedCrowdsale(_openingTime, _closingTime)
    {

    }

}
```

PostDeliveryCrowdsale:

```
contract PostDeliveryCrowdsale is TimedCrowdsale {
  using SafeMath for uint256;

  mapping(address => uint256) public balances;

  /**
   * @dev Withdraw tokens only after crowdsale ends.
   */
  function withdrawTokens() public {
    require(hasClosed());
    uint256 amount = balances[msg.sender];
    require(amount > 0);
    balances[msg.sender] = 0;
    _deliverTokens(msg.sender, amount);
  }

  /**
   * @dev Overrides parent by storing balances instead of issuing tokens right away.
   * @param _beneficiary Token purchaser
   * @param _tokenAmount Amount of tokens purchased
   */
  function _processPurchase(
    address _beneficiary,
    uint256 _tokenAmount
  )
    internal
  {
    balances[_beneficiary] = balances[_beneficiary].add(_tokenAmount);
  }

}
```

I can buy tokens, but when i call the **withdrawTokens()** function its throwling a error. The **balances** mapping of the crowdsale contract returns the token amount that i already buyed.

Any idea will be appreciated!

Comment: Just a guess, but what does `hasClosed()` do, and is it possible it's returning `false`?

Comment: unfortunately no, crowdsale.hasClosed.call() = true

Comment: Okay, next candidate is `require(amount > 0)`. Perhaps `amount == 0`. If that's not it, then  presumably `_deliverTokens(msg.sender, amount)` is failing, but I don't see the code for that function, so only you know how that might fail.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem! I had to transfer the balance (tokens) of the token contract to the crowdsale contract. Okay, I recognize a noob error.